# how to paint link that i visit and link that i dont visit with green ? (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have link in my webform

how to do that even i visit or not visit the color will be green ?

thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend not removing the visual hint for the user. Different colors serve as a valuable information for the user, where he already navigated to. _(I once read that Google tested tens of different variants of blue just to get the one that drives the most clicks.)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with CSS.

```
a, a:visited {
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the :visited css pseudo class

```
a, a:visited { color: green; }
```